# Dynamically calculate height between sets of elements

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add CSS to visually connect sets of elements. I want to dynamically calculate the height between divs with a class of `start` and divs with a class of `end`.

What's in between these divs can vary. For instance, the flow could be:

```
<div class="start"></div>
<div class="multi"></div>
<div class="end"></div>
```

Or it could be:

```
<div class="start"></div>
<div class="multi"></div>
<div class="multi"></div>
<div class="multi"></div>
<div class="end"></div>
```

So the height needs to vary.

I am unsure of how to achieve this using `offset` or `position` as all attempts have produced the same height for all instances.

I have made a fiddle to illustrate my struggle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ux3vf0mg/

As you can see, the rounded border should start at `start` and end at `end` but in fact it goes past or falls short of those points.

How can I dynamically calculate the height for each instance?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want your rounded border to run alongside `start, multi, end` - or just along whatever is in the middle (`multi`)?

Comment: @jonuleis I want it run along side start multi and end

Comment: Ok just to clarify. Try removing the first start and end block and run the same code for the many multi divs. Is that the output you want. As you have multiple start/end blocks so the jquery is only calculating the height and offset of the first start and first end element it finds. You need to loop through or do it seperately for each instance of the start/end block.

Comment: @nasirt not quite the rounded rectangle should start at the red blocks top line and end at the blue blocks top line

Comment: ok working on the solution

Comment: Added the answer. you were very close. Just needed to subtract the end class heigth from total height :). Happy coding. Dont forget to mark and vote the correct answer, whoever's it may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you correctly, you want the `other-container` to start from the top of the `start` div top and end at the top of the `end` div block no matter how much middle div content is present.

Firstly, the code you are writing is applying the same calculated totalheight to both the `other-container` divs because there are 2 start/end blocks and the jquery code is only picking the first elements it finds of the start/end block.

For you to run and calculate the code for both the start/end blocks. I suggest you put the blocks in a parent container with same class and then run the .each function for that class to calculated their seperate heights for their `other blocks`. Below is the sample code i adjusted using your jsfiddle code to give the desired output.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/JyZZeE

What i have done is wrapped each start/end block within a div with class `block-container`, then in jquery ran a .each on the `block-container` class to calculated the height individually and apply it to it's `other-container`.

**[Edit for solution without parent/wrapping block]**

If you dont want to add each start/end block in a wrapper then you can use the following solution to work with multiple start/end divs within the same parent block

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/KvexPm

Hope this helps. Happy coding;

Comment: Thanks very much for this but is there no way to calculate this without the wrapping container? Each start, multi, and end block is added dynamically via a template structure would you suggest I do another calculation for which blocks have a start multi or end class and wrap them ?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the solution without wrapping container. Happy coding